# How to add multiple spaces between two strings in ruby .rb file method for pdf generation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

I want to have more spaces between two strings in my rails pdf file.I tried adding more spaces like "    " but it is assuming to have a single space.And also, I am not able to use "\n" for my pdf file. The "\n" is not working for pdf generation.
Give a quick solution for it.
Eg:

`self.details.map{|i|text = i.name + "    " + dob + "\n"}`

which gives the output :

`ndev                                             12/12/2020`

`dev                                              12/12/2020`

Comment: Wicked PDF generates PDF from HTML, not plain text. In HTML, whitespace is largely ignored. You _could_ use `<pre>` or the CSS `white-space` property, but it makes much more sense to have an actual HTML/CSS based layout.

Comment: additional to @Stefan comment, you should also be able to use `&nbsp;` in there as the HTML non-breaking space, if you don't want preformatted text

Answer (score 0):

Use the constant `Prawn::Text::NBSP` instead of plain spaces, i.e.

```rb
self.details.map {|i| text = i.name + (Prawn::Text::NBSP * 4) + i.dob + "\n" }
```

The constant contains the Unicode symbol for a non-breaking space and Prawn knows how to correctly handle this for AFM and TTF/OTF fonts.